# Is there a way to intercept http request coming from import?

Tags: angular

In our angular app, we're importing 3rd party component like:

`import someComponent from 'some-package';`

that sends http requests to some url to get actual `<script>`s for the component.

is there a way to intercept those requests and direct them somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for the 3rd party component? You could change the requests/URIs yourself. Otherwise you could conditionally rewrite the requests. This will be slightly different depending on how they're making the requests. If they're using `HttpClient`, you could [provide an interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses). If they're using `fetch()` or similar, you could [proxy the related object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Cannot stress enough how much easier it will be to fork their code and update the URIs yourself if that's possible.

Comment: not sure i get why the question was downvoted. its a very plausible usecase.

Comment: @DM they actually put `<script>` into the html. so, probably some kind of `appendChild` or similar.